# Any ideas what I need? To solve "find path of possible cases" in limited conditions

Tags: c, algorithm, path-finding

I [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxKav.png)
This problem is a problem of counting the number of ways to find a path.
This provides all path array and N(y),M(x) (array size)

so i write a code below

In summary this code, if one array is 1, the sum of the values ​​of the lower 3 arrays is added, stored, and uploaded.

```
010   020
101-->101
```

All my attempts have failed, but since I haven't made any progress on this code for more than two days, so I'm posting a question here...
What am I missing in this problem?

The full code is this.

https://github.com/shirohebiui/BAEKJOON/blob/main/24392eng.c

```
ex)
input\>
5 5
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
output\>
9
```

```
    //x width = 1
        if(m==1)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                sum+=arr[i][0];
            }
            if(sum == n)
                sum = 1;
            else
                sum = 0;
            printf("%lld\n", sum);
            return 0;
        }
    
        //y length = 1
        if(n==1)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                sum+=arr[0][j];
            }
            printf("%lld\n", sum);
            return 0;
        }
    
        //x, y >=2 case
        for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i][j]==1)
                {
                if(j==0)        //left end
                    arr[i][j] = arr[i+1][j]+arr[i+1][j+1];
                else if(j==m)   //right end
                    arr[i][j] = arr[i+1][j-1]+arr[i+1][j];
                else            //middle
                    arr[i][j] = arr[i+1][j-1]+arr[i+1][j]+arr[i+1][j+1];
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Thenb please try to create a [mre], and [edit] yout question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I modified some of your code, specifically the for loops and ifs by fixing the curly braces. Is this the expected output?

[image: Code run with gcc on Linux]

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
long long arr[1000][1000]={0};
int main()
{
    //data input
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            scanf("%lld", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    long long sum=0;

    //x width = 1
    if(m==1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            sum+=arr[i][0];
        }
        if(sum == n){
            sum = 1;
        }else{
            sum = 0;
        }
        printf("%lld\n", sum);
        return 0;
    }

    //y length = 1
    if(n==1)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            sum+=arr[0][j];
        }
        printf("%lld\n", sum);
        return 0;
    }

    //x, y >=2 case
    for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i][j]==1)
            {
            if(j==0){        //left end
                arr[i][j] = arr[i+1][j]+arr[i+1][j+1];
            }else if(j==m){   //right end
                arr[i][j] = arr[i+1][j-1]+arr[i+1][j];
            }else            //middle
                arr[i][j] = arr[i+1][j-1]+arr[i+1][j]+arr[i+1][j+1];
            }
            }
        }
    }
    //test code
    printf("=============\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            printf("%ld ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
        sum+=arr[0][j]%1000000007; //This value is the condition specified in the problem
    }
    printf("%lld\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that using curly braces for even 1-line if statements and loops is generally better because it increases readability.

Comment: The `long long arr[1000][1000]` is somewhat adventurous as a local variable. 8mb will break some stacks.

Comment: I thought I edited that out, but since I was using vi, I couldn't copy the code and had to reproduce it here. Thanks for telling me!

Comment: Yes, the output you are expecting is correct.
Next time I'll pay more attention to readability.

I tried moving arr to global as well, but it still doesn't work.
I'm trying to solve a problem on this site(https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/24392). My code does not pass the code inspection provided here. So it seems there is an exception in my code or something wrong with the code. :(

Comment: @pungsock Please note that while this code might work and pass the tests of that site, it's not what would be considered good code. Few examples on or for so-called "competition" or "judge" sites tend to be good. If I was a teacher for you, or a code-reviewer on a company, code like that would not be accepted. The big problem is that habits tend to stick, bad or good. And learning from the bad habits, bad code or sometimes even invalid code on such sites will not make you a good programmer.

Comment: Being a @Python Nerd, you are understandably not used to braces - they are unbalanced in your code, which kind of belies your assertion _using curly braces_ _increases readability._

Comment: I also use C often, I set my username long ago